# Why don't images in iCloud appear as available in iMovie on IOS?

Tags: ios, imovie

I want to create a full video on IOS device but use a predetermined asset for an intro screen. I have added a JPEG to my iCloud account formatted to video screen size.
I then created a movie project on my phone (6 plus) and clicked "add media " icon, then browse to iCloud and I can see the file, but it isn't selectable. So what am I missing? Is it a file format issue?

[image: icloud selection]

[image: imagenotsellectable]

Comment: Do you have the latest version?

Comment: Yes, iMovie is up to date, and IOS is as well.

Comment: Could you try saving the file with an another file extension? Like .png or .gif

Comment: Okay, I tried both and they all still appear greyed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked on my iMovie and it seams like you can only import video from iCloud Drive and the tab you are in will only accept video files, that's why the image file is greyed out.

To use that image in you iMovie project I recommend that you save the image to your local Camera Roll from iCloud Drive and then import it to iMovie.

You can save the image file to your Camera Roll from iCloud Drive with a application that allow you to manage your iCloud Drive. I use "Documents" by Reedle (it's free on the AppStore).

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I guess I either have to make sure the still images I want to use are in my gallery or use and app like you suggested to pull icloud images into the gallery.